# Update List items using workflow - multiple items

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow, lookup-column, updatelistitems

I have two SharePoint lists, one list contains Tools and the other list contains Jobs.
On the Jobs List, I enter a new job. I then will select the Tools needed for the job. The Tools are in a lookup field (allows multiple values) that I can select multiple Tool items for the job and adds them to the Jobs List.
After you select the Tools needed for the Jobs List they’re populated list the Tools column looks like:  tool1; tool2; tool3; tool4;

Example:

```
JOB                        TOOLS                                                          
Install door               tool1; tool2; tool3; tool4;
```

I created a workflow with SharePoint designer 2010
I have a basic update list item workflow that changes the Tools List Status Column from In to Out.
The work flow only processes the first Item and then stops.

How do I get the workflow continue to process all of the Tools selected to the 
Jobs list and update status field to Out on the Tools list?

Example:
Set Variable: Mytoolsid to Current Item: MyTools

then update item in Mytools

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not do stuff like this out of the box. You will need code in some way. Either a custom workflow, or Javascript in the list form. The [SPServices library](https://spservices.codeplex.com/) by Marc Anderson has the JS based tools, but it has a learning curve, especially if you are not familiar with JS and JQuery.